# RabbitMQ best practice for infrequent message publishing

Tags: multithreading, rabbitmq, pika

I have several message producing threads that only publish messages infrequently (e.g short burst of messages, then sleep for 6 hours). Is it better to start a new connection and close it after publishing? Or is it better to keep the connection alive via heartbeat?

As for the consumer thread. It doesn't take very long to process each message (within heartbeat interval), but most of the time the receiver connection is idle as no message being published. I noticed that very often, the connection will be dropped if it remains idle for too long. Is it the expected behaviour? I thought connection only drops when the whole consumer thread is blocked by long running message processing function, such that no heartbeat can be received for the entire heartbeat interval.

Answer (score 0):

from what I know, you can close producer connection without worry about anything after your sending is done.

when you deal with consumer tho, you have to be careful. RabbitMQ uses connection to determine the consumer liveness. if connection is close, or dropped, rabbit will consider this consumer is done or dead.

in other words, if you don't enable auto-ack(auto acknowledge), while your message is been processing, message status will be nack, meaning it's not acked yet. if you drop consumer connection right now, rabbit will consider this consumer dead and put the message to status=ready, so other consumers from the consumer group can then pick up this message.

in your case, connection been dropped probably indicates some issues, I suggest you to turn on debug mode to see details debug message from your consumer rabbit client. also, you can check rabbit server as well, there might be some clue there too.